# socket io connection refused with laravel echo

Tags: laravel, socket.io, echo

I keep getting a connection refused error:
 https://example.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LqznKQ9 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

On the vps ip tables is disabled, no firewall, laravel echo starts fine.

Config file:

```
{
"appKey": "3c2ksu8rn9qhjg3c1t5p2k8ril2st0drid6h81bgumb1k5hbgt3790orreb1",
"authHost": "https://example.com:443",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "verifyAuthPath": true,
    "verifyAuthServer": false,
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": "example.com",
"port": "6001",
"referrers": [],
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "/etc/apache2/ssl/example_com.crt",
"sslKeyPath": "/etc/apache2/ssl/example.key",
"protocol": "https"
}
```

Any tips what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your laravel echo server json file, please.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy added it

Answer (score 0):

Did you start laravel-echo-server with command: laravel-echo-server start ? Or you can create the js file with code:

```
var echo = require('laravel-echo-server');
echo.run();
```

and run this something this: node server.js